# Add marker on clicking openseadragon viewer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openseadragon

I want to basically do what is asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714327/js-openseadragon-when-click-on-the-component-add-a-marker) link. However I have a few questions, is canvas-click event predefined is openseadragon? Also this method gives me errors `Cannot read property of null (reading 'addHandler')`. Is there any other method to add marker to the clicking point in openseadragon viewer.

EDIT1: Apparently i was calling addHandler before adding an image to osd viewer. So this situation is fixed now. So now I have an icon that I want to add at the point of click on viewer.

EDIT2: Okay so the method mentioned in the above answer worked. But I had to declare an img tag and pass its id to addOverlay method. Also it seems we can add label to only 1 point using this. What I have is an icon (chakraui icon precisely) and want to attach that to the viewer multiple times. So everytime I click on viewer it should attach a new instance of icon to the point of click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a new one each time, you'll need to create the overlay element yourself rather than referring to it by ID.

```
viewer.addHandler('canvas-click', function(event) {
  var viewportPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);  
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'my-icon';
  viewer.addOverlay({
    element: element,
    location: viewportPoint
  });
});
```

I haven't tested this code but this should be the basic idea.